# Check if a user has authorized a script before trying to execute anything that requires authorization

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a Google Sheet that has an [`onOpen(e)` Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopene). Obviously that'll run fine, without needing any authorization and it'll show the user the menu.

When the user clicks the menu item it'll execute a function that requires authorization, for example it will call `DriveApp...`.

The first time the user clicks the menu item it'll ask them to authorize the script.

What I'd like to do is, before GAS asks the user to authorize if needed, check if the script does need to be authorized and do something else, that doesn't need authorization (like showing an alert).

I know I have to use [`getAuthorizationStatus()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/authorization-info#getAuthorizationStatus()) but I can't figure out how.

I started with the code below, but as soon as I select the `one` menu item, it asks me to authorize and doesn't log anything. So I'm not sure how to check authorization status...

```
function onOpen(e)
{
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu("Menu")
        .addItem("One", "one")
        .addItem("Two", "two")
        .addToUi();
}

function one()
{
    var a = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
    console.log(a.getAuthorizationStatus());
    console.log(a.getAuthorizationUrl());
    var d = DriveApp.getFolders();
}

function two()
{

}
```

Comment: `two` was just an example. It too will call services that need authorization. RE the link you shared, I could alter what the menu calls to a different function if its not authorized, I think. I will need to test.+

Comment: What `alert` are you looking to show?

Comment: If the code is not authorized I want to show a help message first. The sheet will be shared as a template and the end-users that'll be making copies of it are not experienced with the authorization dialog so I want a pre-help to explain what'll happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to request specific authorization only when the user calls the function(s) that require it. Unfortunately, Apps Script doesn't work like that.

Some functions like `onOpen()` and `onEdit()` can run without any authorization, but calling any other function will prompt authorization *if authorization is required anywhere in the script*. (Even if the code requiring it is commented out.)

So even if you were to follow an example like the one listed in the example [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#the_complete_lifecycle), your script would still prompt for authorization when selecting menu option "One". In the example below, I check for authorization, but because `one()` requires authorization, I'm not allowed to call the custom `authorizeScript()` function until *after* authorizing the script.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Menu");
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.LIMITED) { // Unauthorized
    menu.addItem("Authorize", "authorizeScript");
  } else { // Authorized
    menu.addItem("One", "one");;
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}

function authorizeScript() {
   console.log("authorizeScript");  // No auth required
}

function one() {
  var d = DriveApp.getFolders(); // Auth required
}
```

Please also note that, to check authorization status, I'm using the event object described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#open).

Comment: This is what I thought. Thank you!

Comment: Does this only work for add-ons? I'm attempting to use this code with a container bound script and it's always showing up as unauthorized even after I've gone through the authorization process? Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Even as a container bound script I can't get this to work.  It seems that AuthMode is always LIMITED.  The Else clause never executes, even after authorizing the script.  You never get a Menu>One choice, always Menu>Authorize script.

I can't seem to find a way to get this example to work.

Comment: I have to agree with @DrDogmar. This doesn't work with embeded script, at least embeded in Spreadsheet. Always get LIMITED.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a another project without permissions:

> Tools>Script editor> New> Project:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Readme!')
    .addItem('Click here!', 'howTo')
    .addToUi();
}

function howTo() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(
    `You would need to authorize this script first!
Our privacy policy is simple.... No data is captured or logged or sent to servers.
Anything that happens happens in your sheet`
  );
}
```

Another much more complicated way to do  this in a single project is by limiting scopes(to empty array) to the project by editing the manifest file. But then you would have no inbuilt auth flow. You would need a complicated oauth flow based only on alerts.